# ImmutableList does not extend List?

Tags: java, collections, gs-collections

When I dig into the gs-collection source for `ImmutableList`, it does not extends `java.util.List`. However the class javadoc mentioned that All ImmutableList implementations must implement the `java.util.List`.

Why must ask the implementation to implement `java.util.List` and not the `ImmutableList` itself to extend `java.util.List`?

Comment: What *does* it extend?

Comment: At its root, it extends `java.lang.Iterable`

Comment: Strange design. Instead of putting an unenforceable requirement into the Javadoc they could just have written `extends java.util.List` and have it enforced automatically.

Comment: I agree, and this gives me headache because I don't want to use interface from gs-collections specific. I still want to use `java.util.List` without caring the underlying implementation.

Comment: Nevertheless the only person who is going to provide a useful answer is the author, and unless you get him here all you will get is more or less uninformed guesswork.

Comment: Note: GS Collections has migrated to the Eclipse Foundation and is now Eclipse Collections - https://www.eclipse.org/collections/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Why doesn't `ImmutableList` extend `List`?**

[`ImmutableCollection`](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/99505b9ab5d1d7c5cf20d0b758b4c3a195ba5f53/collections-api/src/main/java/com/gs/collections/api/collection/ImmutableCollection.java) doesn't extend `java.util.Collection` (and [`ImmutableList`](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/blob/99505b9ab5d1d7c5cf20d0b758b4c3a195ba5f53/collections-api/src/main/java/com/gs/collections/api/list/ImmutableList.java) doesn't extend `java.util.List`) because `Collection` has mutating methods like `add()` and `remove()`. If immutable collections had these methods, they would always have to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. For users of immutable collections, it would be strange to see `add()` and `remove()` in auto-complete choices as callable methods.

**Why does the Javadoc impose a contract that all `ImmutableList` implementations also implement `List`?**

It comes down to equality. An `ImmutableList` ought to equal a `List`, assuming both lists have the same contents in the same order. [`List.equals()` imposes a Javadoc contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) which states:

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both
>   lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two lists are equal.

What does it mean that "the specified object is also a list?" We can see in `AbstractList.equals()` that it means `instanceof List`.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;
    ...
}
```

So all `ImmutableList` implementations must also implement `List` for `equals()` to work in a symmetric way. The immutable collection factories already hide implementation details like the fact that an immutable list with a single element is implemented by an `ImmutableSingletonList`. It also winds up hiding the `List` interface.

[image: ImmutableList class diagram]

**Interop**

A benefit of this design is that `ImmutableList` can be cast to `List` which is important for interop with existing APIs.

```
// Library method - cannot refactor the parameter type
public void printAll(List<?> list)
{
    for (Object each : list)
    {
        System.out.println(each);
    }
}

ImmutableList<Integer> immutableList = Lists.immutable.with(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> castList = immutableList.castToList();
printAll(castList);
// also works
printAll((List<?>) immutableList);

// throws UnsupportedOperationException
castList.add(4);
```

**Note:** I am a developer on [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/wiki).

Comment: Thanks for long answer, it makes sense, but I'm guessing that is one flavor of design. Personally I'd prefer to have the add() and remove() to throw UnsupportedOperationException rather than to call castToList(). Developer should know that if the code is using ImmutableList, add and remove won't work and that's developer's issue rather than design issue.But I guess that's just personal opinion. Thanks again for the answer

Comment: I think you might be interested in UnmodifiableMutableList, and its factory method MutableList.asUnmodifiable(). I kept this answer limited to ImmutableList but feel free to ask a new question about the differences and I'll come back and write more.

Comment: I understand UnmodifiableMutableList (the name is very explicit), but what I'm asking is why not making the ImmutableList to extend List, throw UnsupportedOperationException on add and remove, but retain the immutability of the list and the objects it contains.

Comment: What you're describing would certainly work. It came down to design tradeoffs. UnsupportedOperationExceptions are confusing and tough to deal with, though arguably no more confusing than the class diagram above. If we had mutating methods on ImmutableList, we might as well pull them up to the parent, ListIterable. Then MutableList and ImmutableList would become empty marker interfaces, which is odd. We could delete them, but then ListIterable.add() may or may not throw. The downside of the current design is interop. The upside is the ability to clearly express intent, especially for fields.